# Define html form outside tabset in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have issue with form value

please check code

```
<form name="testform" ng-submit="savedata(formdata);" class="css-form" novalidate>
    <tabset class="tab-container">
        <tab heading="tab1">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name"
               ng-model="formdata.name" required="">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </form>
```

controller code

```
 $scope.savedata = function(formdata){
      console.log(formdata) // result is undefined it should be contain name
    }
```

so i have problem with form data,if form inside tab then i can receive value in savedata function but form outsite tabset then value is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like this

**controller code**

```
$scope.formdata = {}; //you need to define like this
$scope.savedata = function(formdata){
      console.log(formdata) // result will be contain name
    }
```